# How can Git track a file in your repo but not overwrite it from someone else's branch?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I have a .htaccess file with specific settings inside it that only work for my machine.

When I pull in changes from another persons branch I always have to undo the changes made.

I think I can do `git checkout file hash` to get the original file back (is that correct? If not can someone show me the correct command) but is there not a way I can tell Git to track the file on my branches but to never pull down the file from another remote branch?

On a similar note: how can you have git track a particular file but never push it to a remote branch. Eg I have a file with password details inside it but if I'm storing my file publicly on GitHub then I don't want that file pushed up.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe add `.htaccess` to `.gitignore` ??

Comment: There is no way to track but not push. What git tracks what git pushes. You shouldn't need to track if you aren't pushing it anyways. Just add it to `.gitinore`.

Comment: Adding file to gitignore means it's not tracked at all but I would like the file and its changes to be tracked

Comment: Also, with regards to comment about tracked file always being pushed because otherwise it shouldn't be tracked. What if the file holds important database password details but the code that connects to the database changes? I want to track code changes but just not have the file pushed online

Comment: You could generate that file (with some e.g. python or shell script), and have the variable|secret part of it appropriately inserted. Then the skeleton or template could by managed by `git` but not the private part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to restore the file to what it had been in a previous version is actually

```
git checkout commit file
```

With the arguments in the opposite order of what was in the question.  The commit can either be a hash or any other way of referring to a commit such as a branch or tag name.

You could setup git to automatically keep your version of the `.htaccess` file by specifying a custom merge driver.

To do this, first you'd need to define the merge driver in the git config, and then specify that that merge file should be used for the `.htaccess` file.

```
git config merge.mine.driver 'touch %A'
echo .htaccess merge=mine >> .gitattributes
```

But, this would not be a good idea if your local branch will ever be merged into the branch from which you're pulling changes. This would be recording that changes to that file have been merged even though they're actually being completely ignored. So if your branch were merged back into the other branch all changes to that file would likely be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep it on a local `branch` and merge it with the `master` when you pull the changes.